# The issues of data passing

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, notifications

I like to pass data from ServicesActivity.java to NotificationView.java through notification services. But the data passing is correct at the first times, when I send another data into it, it doesn't updated its previous data.As you seen, the logcat output below,first times, I sent two data into notification and the output it passed at the NotificationView.java is no problem.After that,I re-send three data into it and its output at NotificationView.java still is two data. Whatever I sent how many data into notification, its output at NotificationView.java still follow its first times output.Here is the logcat output:

```
11-21 10:42:03.645: D/String(25694): admin,admin
11-21 10:42:33.645: D/String(25694): admin,admin,admin
11-21 10:42:06.308: D/how(25694): admin,admin
11-21 10:42:36.518: D/how(25694): admin,admin
```

**The Log.d("String",str) is at displayNotification() of ServicesActivity.java and Log.d("how",i) is at NotificationView.java.

ServicesActivity.java

```
public class ServicesActivity extends Activity {

IntentFilter intentFilter;
int notification = 1;
String datapassed; 
String str = "";
String[] data;
int dlength;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_services);

    intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction(MyService.MY_ACTION);
    registerReceiver(intentReceiver, intentFilter);
}

public void startService(View view){
    startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(),MyService.class));
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "start",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

public void stopService(View view){
    stopService(new Intent(getBaseContext(),MyService.class));
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "stop",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}


private BroadcastReceiver intentReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    datapassed = intent.getStringExtra("DATAPASSED");
    if(datapassed.length()>0){

        data = datapassed.split("[*]");
        dlength = data.length;

        for(int i=0;i<dlength;i++){
            if(i==dlength-1){
                str += String.valueOf(data[i]);                 
            }else{
                str += String.valueOf(data[i]) + ",";
            }   
        }
        Log.d("dataServices",str);
        displayNotification();
            str = "";           
    }
    }
    };

    protected void displayNotification(){
        Intent i = new Intent(this,NotificationView.class);
        i.putExtra("notification", notification);
        i.putExtra("name",str);
        Log.d("String",str);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, 0);

        NotificationManager mnotis =(NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Notification notis = new Notification(R.drawable.notices2,"Reminder:You have " + dlength + " new friend request",System.currentTimeMillis());
        notis.setLatestEventInfo(this,"Friend Request", str + "has sent you a friend request",pi);
        notis.vibrate = new long[]{100,250,100,500};
        mnotis.notify(0, notis);
    }
  }
```

NotificationView.java

```
public class NotificationView extends Activity{

String[] people;
ListView lv;
Button btn1,btn2;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view);  
    NotificationManager mnotis =(NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mnotis.cancel(getIntent().getExtras().getInt("notificationID"));
    String i = getIntent().getExtras().getString("name");
    people = i.split("[,]");
    Log.d("how",i);

    lv= (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    btn1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.acceptbtn);
    btn2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.closebtn);
    ArrayAdapter<String> list = new ArrayAdapter<String>(NotificationView.this,R.layout.friendlist_item, R.id.friend_name,people);
    lv.setAdapter(list); 

    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            finish();
        }
    });
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, if you only change the extras, Android will use the existing (cached) `PendingIntent`. Use the `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` flag to force it to create a new one with the specified extras.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT

Comment: It works! Thanks.
References for others: PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);